# Basis, Ordered Basis, and Linear Independence

Tags: linear-algebra

I am given

$$
\mathscr B=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}\right\}
$$

and told that this is a basis for $\mathbb R^4$.

I figured that this is equivalent to

$$
\mathscr B=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}\right\}
$$

and found that its linear combination

$$
\left\{\begin{pmatrix}a+b+c\\a+b\\b\\b\end{pmatrix}:a,b,c\in\mathbb R\right\}\neq\mathbb R^4
$$

because $\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4\end{pmatrix}^T\in\mathbb R^4$ would imply that $b=3$ and $b=4$.

Did the problem writer make a mistake?

If $\mathscr B$ were an ordered basis, then would the problem be any different?

Comment: Your $B$ is indeed not a basis for $\Bbb R^4$. Another way of seeing this is the fact that $\Bbb R^4$ has dimension $4$, so it cannot be spanned by a set of fewer than $4$ vectors. I'm guessing it's a typo in the book.

Comment: Yes, it's (probably) a typo. A basis can't have repeated vectors.

Comment: @SolidSnake, I see. What if it is an ordered basis?

Comment: @Josué It doesn't matter. If you have repeated vectors in a (ordered or not) basis $(v_1,...,v_n)$, say $v_1=v_2$, you can do the following non-trivial null linear combination: $v_1 - v_2 = 0$ so the set of vectors would be linearly dependent.

Comment: @SolidSnake, if you write your comments into an answer, then I will accept it. Thank you.